# VBA not changig data in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

this is going to be something really really silly! i have this code:

```
Public Sub SortMyData()

Dim i As Integer
Dim N_Values As Integer
Dim columnC As String

N_Values = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To N_Values
    Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "0"

    If Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
        Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value / 100

        ElseIf (Cells(i, 3).Value) > 1000000 Then
            columnC = (Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000000) & "Mb"

        ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = Null Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = 0

    Else
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

the code runs fine but the data on the cells does not get changed accordingly. if use debug.print it does print the results that i am looking for.
please help!

here is a sample of the data:

```
1984000
40000000
230000
230000
230000
1984000
230000
16000000
```

and this is what the debug.print gives me which is the correct result but not showing on the actual cells (this is just an example and not respective to the data provided):

```
2.048Mb
1.984Mb
230kb
16Mb
230kb
16Mb 
8Mb
2.007Mb
230kb
```

i still need to add the IF statement for the kb part but i have got that covered.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Never mind, you never define columnC... but then give it a value in the first ElseIf statement.

Comment: @a-burge yes, i have amnded the question and added the data.

Comment: i have giben it the value of {columnC = (Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000000) & "Mb"}

Comment: Your logic is not clear to me.  Perhaps if you write in words what you expect to happen.   Or provide the expected results after the macro runs based on your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your logic is meant to do, but it looks like one those ElseIfs should be a separate If block.

columnC doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Is this more what you were looking for?

```
Public Sub SortMyData()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim N_Values As Integer

    N_Values = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 6 To N_Values
        Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "0"

        If Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
            Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value / 100
        Else
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If

        If (Cells(i, 3).Value) > 1000000 Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = (Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000000) & "Mb"
        ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = Null Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code should solve the problem caused by the String `columnC`. But just to make this clear: Setting a cell's value to that cell's value is absolutely not redundant. It removes formulas in the specific cell, just like `Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`.

Comment: @bobajob fantastic mate!.. thanks for that but may i ask why did i need a separate IF Statement instead of using ElseIF? i just want to keep my code as tidy and simple as possible.

Comment: ElseIf will only be run if the original If is not true. In your example, the changes to column C were only happening if column B was already formatted to a percentage.